# spring-cloud-config connects and finds config server but can't get config data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

i have configured a config server to get configurations from a local git repo and its endpoint 'http://localhost:8889/limits-service/default' working properly.
[image: calling the config server end point]

but when a config client tries to connect to the config server the client does not get any config data and returns the local config data resides in the client application.properties file.
this logs appears when running the client app.
[image: this logs appears when running the client app]
and on the server side, it seems that the server gets the request and handles it.
this logs appears on the server side
[image: this logs appears on the server side]

and here are the return values, when I try to test the new config values on the client side, fetched from the server I find that still the local values with no updates.
values are not updated
[image: values are not updated]
and here are the properties files for the client and server and the local Git repo
client properties file
[image: client properties file]
server properties file
[image: server properties file]
Git repo properties file
[image: Git repo properties file]

so can anyone please tell me why config values are not getting updated though the client connects to the server and the server handles the request properly?

I am trying to connect a config client with a config server to update the client config values but the values are not getting updated though the client connects to the server and the server handles the request properly.

Answer (score 0):

the problem just was that I used the wrong method to read the updated value from the properties file.
i used this and it now working proberly
[image]